# how i can remove quotes around string

Tags: ruby, string

Hi i want to remove quotes around this string

```
str =  "[Date.UTC(2012,07,03,04,07,09),2.0]"
```

and want result like this

```
  [Date.UTC(2012,07,03,04,07,09),2.0]
```

Any help will be apperciated...

Thanks

Comment: Giving us more context would be great.  Is your first line rendered into a `<script>` block?  Can you show us your ERB line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval). It takes a string and evaluates it as ruby code.

```
str = "[Date.UTC(2012,07,03,04,07,09),2.0]"
a = eval str
```

By the way, this string isn't valid ruby code. Primarily because `09` is parsed as octal number, and `09` is not a valid octal number. Secondly, there's no `UTC` method on `Date` class (in the stdlib, anyway).

### Edit

If you want to take this string and pass it to javascript, then just render it in the template.

```
# action.html.erb
<%= javascript_tag do %>    
  <%= str %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: give me error                                                          1.9.3-p194 :005 > a = eval str
SyntaxError: (eval):1: Invalid octal digit
[Date.UTC(2012,07,03,04,07,09),2.0]
                             ^
 from (irb):5:in `eval'
 from (irb):5

Comment: Note that although this is what you want to do here, it is not recommended to do this unless you are very confident that the data may not harm you.

Comment: i need this to pass these to javascript

Comment: @ali, just send it. This is not ruby.

Comment: Original string looks like Javascript.  Won't be able to `eval` JS.

Comment: is there no way to take result like i want?

Answer (score 2):

If you're truly just asking about string manipulation... If the quotes are at the beginning and end of the string...

```
str = "abcdef"
trimmed = str[1..-2] #equals "bcde"
```